# Trigger to update a user id with the count of records he approved

Tags: apex, trigger

I  have a requirement. I have an object named `Building__c` and it has a field named `Validation_Status__s`, which is a picklist. The user updates the `Validation _Status` with APPROVED value. So after every update, delete or undelete operation every user id must reflect the number of records that has been approved. The field `Buildings_validated__c` has been created in User object shows the count.I have framed my trigger like this.

```
Trigger Countrecord on Building__c (after update, after delete , after delete, after insert)

{
Set<Id> BuildingSet = new Set<id>();
Map<String,List <Sighting__c>> userBuldingListMap = new Map<Id,List <Building__c>>();

if ( Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
    for (Building__c s: Trigger.new)
    BuildingSet.add(s.Id);
} else if (Trigger.isDelete){
    for (Building__c s : Trigger.old)
       BuildingSet.add(s.Id);   
}

for (Building__c s:[SELECT Id, Validation_Status__c, Validated_By__c  FROM Sighting__c WHERE Validation_Status__c = 'Approved' WHERE Id IN :BuildingSet])
    userBuildingListMap.put(s.Validated_By__c ,s);

}
```

// Rest Part I am not quite sure how to proceed further.

Please guide me how to proceed with this.
Regards

Comment: you want to display count of approved in every user record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query all records with `Validation status = 'Approved'` using `aggregate` query and then update count.

```
Trigger Countrecord on Building__c (after update, after delete , after delete, after insert)

{
//check if for any record Validation_Status__c changed or if record delete
//logic write here 
Integer reccount = [SELECT count(Id)  FROM Sighting__c WHERE Validation_Status__c = 'Approved' ])
    List<user> userList = new List<user>();
    for(user u : [Select Id,Buildings_validated__c  from user ])
    {
       u.Buildings_validated__c  = reccount ;
      userList.add(u);
     }
   update u;

}
```

Comment: @ReshmiSmiju Because the count is same you can use this code. if you want to update the count with admin profile user or you want any other filters you can add them in query.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: @ReshmiSmiju we are calculating a fresh count with every event. So I think it will work in all case and handle the increment decrement part itself.

Comment: @ReshmiSmiju it will handle bulk data. As of now if this solves your problem you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

hi Below psuedo code is written for a single scenario, which can be extended as you see fit.

```
Trigger Countrecord on Building__c (after update)
{
    Set<Id> BuildingSet = new Set<id>();
    List<user> user_lst = new List<user>();
    Map <Id,Building__c> m_Building_old = Trigger.OldMap;
    List <Building__c> l_Building_new = Trigger.new;
    set<Id> UserIds = new set<userIds> ();

    for(Building__c temp : l_Building_new )
        userIds.add(temp.Validated_By__c);

    Map <Id,User>  userMap = new Map <Id,User>([Select Id, Buildings_validated__c from User where Id IN : userIds]);

    for(Building__c cur_building : l_Building_new )
    {
        if(cur_building.Validation_Status  == 'Approved'  && m_Building_old.get(cur_building.Id).Validation_Status != 'Approved')
        {
            userMap.put(Validated_By__c, userMap.get(Validated_By__c)+1);
        }       
    }
    update userMap.Values() ;
}
```

Comment: Your code has many run time errors. Will fail to execute in many secenario

Comment: As said earlier it is just a pusedo code...

Comment: Yes but `userMap.put(Validated_By__c, userMap.get(Validated_By__c)+1)`  here Validated_By__c not have any reference and if give null `userMap.get(Validated_By__c)` then you will get error.

Comment: yes indeed i agree with you, repeating myself again it is just a pusedo code. All the condition and scenarios need to built around it. It was a vauge idea which was suppose to be developed as seen fit.  Feel Free to optimise :)